Move ownership of uncopiable type
I'm a relatively new Rust dev and this is an issue I've been running into consistently. Sometimes I have data stored within a Vector which I will later move into a new variable, but if the data isn't copiable it wants me to Clone with an error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `X`. move occurs because value has type `Y`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait. I understand that changing ownership would make the original unusable but in this case I won't be reusing the original and this is intended behavior. Is there a way to indicate that I want that behavior or does Rust's safety measures require cloning in this case? Borrowing also isn't an option as I'm passing the result into a function which doesn't take in a reference.
This is a minimum representative example:
struct Uncopiable {}

fn main() {
    let x = vec![Uncopiable {}, Uncopiable {}];
    let _y = x[0];
}


I am no expert a all in rust, but my feeling is that you need to Copy it. Since it can't be borrowed as you said.

To better summarize your question: you want to take ownership of an element in a Vec and destroy the rest? You can easily move non-Copy types, but Vec doesn't allow you to move via the index operator.

Not quite, I want to keep the rest of the data in a Vector after taking ownership of one of its items.

Then, you likely want .remove or .swap_remove as shown in answers for the linked duplicate. Or if you want to avoid moving elements around the Vec and instead put a dummy value where you're taking the element from, then std::mem::replace or std::mem::take like shown here could also be an option.
